# VSCode and Vue 2 plugin TypeScript definitions

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm using VSCode and TypeScript classes for Vue 2 component development. See: [vuejs/vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component).

In my current project I use plugins like `vue-i18n` for translations of labels etc. These plugins extend the Vue components with their own functions like `this.$t(...)` to get a translation by key, but VSCode doesn't recognize / doesn't no off these extensions (or are they mixins?) etc.

How can I learn VSCode that these extension functions exist and intellisense starts working? Can I create my own *.d.ts files? And if so, how can I hook these up so VSCode can find them for intellisense? Any example is welcome. Or link to some example Github repo where this is done?

Comment: there are .d.ts files for vue, if you are looking for them you can find them here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vue

Comment: My question is about creating/using definition files for Vue 2 plugins which add custom functions to the Vue class. I know there are *.d.ts files for Vue itself, but those work fine.

Comment: you can extend those types if you want. Typescript interfaces are open ended, if you add more methods to them they should be picked up by the compiler.

Comment: I wrestled with the same issue and decided to try and add types vue-i18n repository. Work in progress branch is at https://github.com/aom/vue-i18n/tree/typescript-support

Comment: I also opened an issue at vue-i18n repository: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/130

Comment: @aarreoskari Great work! Thanks. I will monitor the issue too.

Comment: @MaartenDocter if you've found a solution, better to post it as an answer instead of an edit to the question

Comment: Thanks @thanksd. I did as you proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is solved now and documented in the Vue TypeScript documentation. It's called ["Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins).

The following snippet is from this page for quick reference:

```
// For example, to declare an instance property $myProperty with type string:

// 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    $myProperty: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vue-i18n` does not provide its own TypeScript types.

Instead, you can use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vue-i18n/index.d.ts):

`npm i -D @types/vue-i18n` or `yarn add -D @types/vue-i18n`

Comment: Hi and welcome!You could significantly improve the quality of your answer by adding more details and explaining what these commands really do and why they answer the question.